# sort the list of links by the name of the link

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting

I have list of links

```
links = [
  '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/24/portfolio/">Packaging Only Demo</a>',
  '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/38/portfolio/">QA Source</a>',
  '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/44/portfolio/">Complete Demo</a>'
]
```

And I need to sort the list by the name of the link.

I tried to sort it with a regular expression but it lasted too long. The list consists of a multitude of references

```
import re
def sorted(x):
  return re.search(r'\>(.*)<', x).group(1)

links = sorted(links, key=sorted)
print(links)
```

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use `etree` to parse the XML/HTML snippets and obtain the text between the `<a>` tags. Then you can use that to as a sorting criterion:

```
from lxml import etree

result = sorted(links,key=lambda x : etree.XML(x).text)
```

So here we invoke the `etree.XML(..)` function to construct an `element` (the `<a>` tag), and with `.text` we obtain the text between the tags. We then thus can use this as the `key` of the sorting.

This results in:

```
>>> result
['<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/44/portfolio/">Complete Demo</a>', '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/24/portfolio/">Packaging Only Demo</a>', '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/38/portfolio/">QA Source</a>']
```

Comment: Neat. One must always use parsers instead of regex.

Comment: Better than my answer and also more safe.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `sorted()` or `sort()` with `str.split()` ?

```
# Or:
# links.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(">")[1].split("<")[0])

sorted_list = sorted(links, key= lambda x: x.split(">")[1].split("<")[0])
```

Output

```
>>> print(sorted_list)

 ['<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/44/portfolio/">Complete Demo</a>',
 '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/24/portfolio/">Packaging Only Demo</a>',
 '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/38/portfolio/">QA Source</a>']
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that extracts the name from a given string; then pass this function as `key` argument to `sort` or `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

[Find online demo](https://repl.it/IcSw/0)

```
import re
links = [
  '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/24/portfolio/">Packaging Only Demo</a>',
  '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/38/portfolio/">QA Source</a>',
  '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/project/44/portfolio/">Complete Demo</a>'
]
def custom_function(k):
  return re.search(r'\>(.*)\<', k).group(1)
print(sorted(links, key=custom_function))
```